# execute an event but the coding from my own class

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

how to execute event from my own class for example I want to execute on click event in button after click it show a message it is my first class but the coding in my own class

Comment: You do that by writing `Button.Click`

Comment: Bear in mind that the accepted answer at the dupe is, in my view, the wrong way to do it. My answer there is the best way to fire the `OnClick` event, but the advice given by @whosrdaddy shows you the right way to solve the problem. Do what he suggests.